# Help with video capture card

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb

Please help with the capture card pinnacle, 710-usb. It works in windows, but recently I switched to ubuntu 14.04, and I can not get it to work. U who have experience in programming help, need a driver for LINUX.

1. The board is designed on the basis of the integrated circuit Cyclone
   TM EP1C3T144C8N manufactured by Altera.
2. Analog-to-digital video conversion has been known and proven 9-bit
   ADC SAA7113H from Philips Semiconductors.
3. Sound transmission is responsible for AC'97 codec EMP202 from EMPIA
   Technology

Answer (score 0):

for the Pinnacle Systems MovieBox Plus (710-USB), a driver for Linux is available for the Pinnacle MovieBox USB video capture/playback device.

Pinnacle MovieBox USB Linux driver can be downloaded from [here](http://pinnaclembusb.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Please tell me how to take advantage of it, download how to install do not understand did not make what comes out

Comment: I don't have the hardware, but once you extract the file just run the file called pmbplay

Comment: `lsusb` shows this device as having ID `2304:0224`, but it appears the linked driver’s `PinnacleMovieBoxInit()` method is looking for `2304:0204`, so the programs never acknowledge the device’s existence.